# Is it normal for tuple() to increase the run time by so much?

Tags: python, runtime

I have a relatively long (20,000 rows) CSV file and a simple function I wrote to open it:

```
def read_prices():
    with open('sp500.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield float(row['Adj Close'].strip())
```

when I time it as it is it takes `3e-05s`:

```
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: read_prices(), number=100))
```

when I time the same function but with `tuple(...)` it takes a whopping `27s`:

```
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: tuple(read_prices()), number=100))
```

Is this normal for `tuple()`? Why might this be? I'm a beginner so ELI5 explanations welcome:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because `read_prices` is not a function - it is actually a [`generator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python). That is because of the `yield` keyword.

As explaind in the [functional programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators):

> Any function containing a [yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) keyword is a generator function;
>   this is detected by Python’s [bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytecode) compiler which compiles the
>   function specially as a result.
>
> When you call a generator function, **it doesn’t return a single
>   value; instead it returns a generator object** that supports the
>   iterator protocol.

So what happens when you run the first `read_prices()` is just a creation of a `generator` object, waiting to be told to `yield` elements.

In the second version, `tuple(read_prices())`, you create the `generator` object as before, but the `tuple()` actually **exhausts** it and `yield`s **ALL** elements at once.

---

A simple demonstration:

```py
>>> def yielder():
...     yield from [1, 2, 3]
...     
>>> y = yielder()
>>> y
<generator object yielder at 0x2b5604090de0>
>>> next(y)
1
>>> list(y)
[2, 3]
>>> tuple(yielder())
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because this is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) `read_prices('SP500.csv')` which is pretty much doing nothing when called like this.

However when you do this `tuple(read_prices('SP500.csv'))` it actions the generator and provides the values.

A generator is a [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration) is actioned by a:

- for loop
- next
- unpacking using `tuple` (as you noted) or `list`

Among other operations involving collection constructs.

Here is a more concrete example of a generator:

```
def f():
    print("First value:")
    yield "first"
    print("Second value:")
    yield "second"
```

Here it is in action:

```
### Nothing prints when called (analogous to your first timeit  without tuple)

In [2]: v = f()

In [3]:

### However when I call `next` the first value is provided:

In [3]: next(v)
First value:
Out[3]: 'first'

## etc, until there is no more values and a "StopIteration` exception is raised:

In [4]: next(v)
Second value:
Out[4]: 'second'

In [5]: next(v)
------------------------------------
...

StopIteration:

## by unpacking using "tuple" the "StopIteration" 
## exception is handled and all the values are provided at once
##  (like your timeit using the tuple):

In [6]: tuple(f())
First value:
Second value:
Out[6]: ('first', 'second')
```